# Component crashes when re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I can see my data the first time I navigate to a different route via a link:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/settings/${door._id}` }}>
```

Inställningar

And it works fine, **but** when I refresh the page my application tries to use data that haven’t been fetched yet, therefor it crashes.  I tried to add a loading screen for my reducer, but that didn’t do the trick. 
Here’s my reducer I created a gist for it: https://gist.github.com/Martinnord/c944f4fd22f4a4ff7e3e0b362e7d4e29

I also reached out to some forums and they gave me a tip to go to the very root of my app before ReactDOM.render and in there, connect to redux state and have an item called `dataIsLoading` or something and if `dataIsLoading` is true I will show a loading thing and if it’s not it renders all my components. Because otherwise I will run into this issue where the selector depends on data in redux, and I can't control when mapStateToProps runs outside of just not rendering that component at all.

But the problem is that I have **absolutely** no idea how to do that, I’ve been trying for hours with no luck. If someone could give me any guidance or tips I would be blessed. And if more code from me is needed, please just let me know.

Thanks for reading.

### Update

Got a request from the comments so I will add some code.

#### mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps, loading, fetchDoorsReducer) => {
  const door = getDoorById(state, ownProps.match.params.itemId)
  const doorId = ownProps.match.params.itemId
  const controller = getControllerById(state, door.controller)

  return {
    doors: door,
    controllers: controller,
    isLoading: state.fetchDoors.isLoading
  }
}
```

How I use `isLoading`: `if (this.props.isLoading) return <p>laddar</p>`

Comment: The description you provide is absolutely spot on.  That's indeed how you should handle this problem.  So what part of applying that solution is getting you stuck?

Comment: Well @gravityplanx I am relatively new to React and Redux. And the stuff I've done with Redux so far is pretty repetitive stuff so nothing more advanced then dispatching actions, fetching data from action (I guess you could call it the regular stuff). Therefor I am unsure how to implement this into code. Should I in my `index.js` file just do `connect()` before `document.getElementById('root')`? Everything is just very unclear and I don't know how to get going. I hope you undestand what I mean. Thanks for replying to my question.

Comment: `${door._id}` does door come from the redux state originally? If so, where you pull the door or doors out of the state, also pull out the `isLoading` flag

Comment: @AHB yes, it is from redux state. I tried to pull it out from my `fetchDoors` but that didn't do the trick. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Can we see the code that you use to pull it from the redux state please?

Comment: Yes of course. I have updated my answer @AHB

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what piece of the functionality you describe you're having difficulty translating to code.  But in case this is it, here's an example that might help you;

```
LoadingWrapper = React.createClass({
    render() {
        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return <SomeLoadingIconHere/>;
        } else {
            return this.props.children;
        }
    }
});
```

and then elsewhere...

```
render() {
    return <LoadingWrapper isLoading={this.props.somePropertyFromRedux}>
        <SomeComponent/>
    </LoadingWrapper>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. You’ve made everything much clearer now. But how would the action and reducer look like for the LoadingWrapper?

Comment: Actions/Reducers are not 1-to-1 with components.  The point of redux is to have shared state across the entirety of the application.  It looks like you already have some concept of what `isLoading` would look like via your pasted `mapStateToProps` function.